# Sizing a subpanel

Tags: subpanel

What size subpanel do I need? Is a 80 amp overkill?

I'm running power to a now she shed. It is 100ft away from main house breaker. I have to install a 30amp double for a pioneer heat and a/c mini split unit and two single 20 amp breakers which will feed ten outlets and six 6 inch can lights.

What would be a proper subpanel size?

Comment: I'd suggest keeping the lights separate from receptacles and use a 15A breaker for the lights. 14Ga wire is slightly less expensive and a lot easier to manipulate for light fixture connections, and unless you're wiring up some throwback incandescent lights, modern lighting as bright as you could possibly want might use 5-10A to light inside and out, at most.

Comment: Once wire gets large enough, aluminum is proven safe.  So we recommend #2 aluminum (e.g. 2-2-2-4 MH feeder) because it's a popular commodity size, and cheap. It is 90A wire, but you won't need 90A so you can save a few bucks by using a 60A breaker, the smallest size that'll take #2.  #14 wire is only less expensive if you already have plenty on hand. If you have to buy a whole 'nother spool of wire, it's the cost of the spool.

Answer (score 5):

The usual recommendation is to go big for future upgrades.

You usually want breaker spaces so a 150 or even a 200 sub panel is not overkill. Usually the big panels are not much more than the small panels.

You do not need to feed the panel at the max it takes.  Using a 60 or bigger feeder breaker for a 200 amp panel is okay.

For wire cost #2 AL will take 90 amps and is usually the cheapest.

Just do a load calculation for your main panel to see how much power/feeder breaker size you can use first.  That will be your limit.